# Whose `I-Node` does `netstat -ap` for unix domain sockets refer to?

Tags: files, socket, inode, netstat

What does `I-Node` mean in the output of `netstat -ap` for unix domain sockets?

It seems not the same as the inode of the socket file:

```
$ netstat -ap
...
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags  Type   State     I-Node  PID/Program name     Path
unix  2    [ ACC ]  STREAM LISTENING 2794745 -              /tmp/emacs1001/server
...

$ sudo ls -i -l /tmp/emacs1001/server 
11796488 srwx------ 1 testme testme 0 Nov 30 19:22 /tmp/emacs1001/server
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get that column with netstat (Proto, Recv-Q, Send-Q, Local Address, Foreign Address, State, PID/Program name). But a socket can have an inode. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659460/how-do-i-find-the-inode-of-a-tcp-socket

Comment: @melds Thanks. Could you be specific of what the inode in netstat output and the inode shown by ls mean respectively?

Answer (score 2):

The inode shown by netstat is the inode of your socket in `sockfs` (a virtual filesystem holding inodes for sockets in the system).

The `sockfs` can also be seen in `/proc/<pid>/fd/` entries - socket fds will be be marked as a link to `socket:[XXXX]` with `XXXX` the inode (This way you can match socket inodes from `netstat` to processes owning an fd for those sockets).

And the inode of the socket file is the inode belonging to the *containing* filesystem; for example, `/tmp/emacs1001/server` is a socket filesystem node on your root `ext4` filesystem (or in your `/tmp` filesystem, if it's a standalone mount)