# How shall I understand the output of `NAME` field of `lsof`?

Tags: lsof

```
$ sudo lsof +E -a -U -p 1480
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
Xorg       717 root   43u  unix 0xffff975eacf2d400      0t0 30862 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM ->INO=28661 1480,lxtermina,3u
dbus-daem  980    t   34u  unix 0xffff975eacf2fc00      0t0 30865 /run/user/1000/bus type=STREAM ->INO=28666 1480,lxtermina,9u
dbus-daem 1073    t   13u  unix 0xffff975eacf2c400      0t0 28664 @/tmp/dbus-vtzJFcQ5Cy type=STREAM ->INO=28663 1480,lxtermina,5u
lxtermina 1480    t    3u  unix 0xffff975eacf2c000      0t0 28661 type=STREAM ->INO=30862 717,Xorg,43u
lxtermina 1480    t    5u  unix 0xffff975eacf2d000      0t0 28663 type=STREAM ->INO=28664 1073,dbus-daem,13u
lxtermina 1480    t    7u  unix 0xffff975eacf2f000      0t0 28665 /run/user/1000/.lxterminal-socket- type=STREAM
lxtermina 1480    t    9u  unix 0xffff975eacf2e800      0t0 28666 type=STREAM ->INO=30865 980,dbus-daem,34u
```

In the `NAME` field, what are the meanings of `INO=28664` and `13u` in

> type=STREAM ->INO=28664 1073,dbus-daem,13u

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See [the `lsof` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html). Its description of the `+E` option says

> Pipe endpoint information is displayed in the NAME column in the form “*PID*,*cmd*,*FDmode*”, where *PID* is the endpoint process ID; *cmd* is the endpoint process command; *FD* is the endpoint file's descriptor; and *mode* is the endpoint file's access mode.
>
> UNIX socket file endpoint information is displayed in the NAME column in the form “type=*TYPE* ->INO=*INODE* *PID*,*cmd*,*FDmode*”, where *TYPE* is the socket type; *INODE* is the i-node number of the connected socket; and *PID*, *cmd*, *FD* and mode are the same as with pipe endpoint information. Note: UNIX socket file endpoint information is available only when the compile flags line of `-v` output contains `HASUXSOCKEPT`.

So `INO=28664` means that the connected socket has inode number 28664, and `13u` means that the endpoint’s file descriptor is 13, and its access mode is read/write.

Comment: Thanks. [What does the inode of a socket mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485780/whose-i-node-does-netstat-ap-for-unix-domain-sockets-refer-to)